# ORA-20000: AOP Server can not be found. Check if it is running at http://api.apexofficeprint.com/

Tags: oracle-apex

During the use of the apex office plugin in order to print the Interactive Report,
I end up with the following pop up error message.

***ORA-20000: AOP Server can not be found. Check if it is running at http://api.apexofficeprint.com/***

Answer (score 0):

```
Make sure APEX_050000 or APEX_050100 schema has the rights to connect to APEX Office Print (http(s)://www.apexofficeprint.com for the Cloud version or your local URL in case of the on-premise version). The script to correct the issue can be found here:
```

For Apex 5.0
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/install.50/e39144/listener.htm#HTMIG29160
For Apex 5.1
http://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMIG/enabling-network-services-in-Oracledb-11g-or-later.htm#HTMIG29160
For Apex 18.1
https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMIG/enabling-network-services-in-Oracle-db11g-or-later.htm#HTMIG29161
For Apex 18.2
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/htmig/enabling-network-services-in-Oracledb-11g-or-later.html#GUID-8D125731-989A-4A51-AFFE-00181729F87F
For Apex 19.1
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmig/enabling-network-services-in-Oracle-db11g-or-later.html
For Apex 19.2
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/htmig/enabling-networkservices-in-Oracle-db-11g-or-later.html
**Note: use the correct script for your database version - for XE use prior to 12c**
For more Info visit: https://www.apexofficeprint.com/docs/ (Section 10.6)